# Can not get log service from osgi-over-slf4j 1.7.7

Tags: osgi

I try to get log service from osgi-over-slf4j (SLF4j v1.7.7) bundle from another bundle but only got null when i call getServiceReference(...).

Here is code in another bundle that try to get a log service.

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" ID State Name");
    Bundle[] bundles = context.getBundles();
    for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
        printBundle(bundle.getBundleId(),
        getStateString(bundle.getState()), (String) bundle
            .getHeaders().get(Constants.BUNDLE_NAME),
        bundle.getLocation(), bundle.getSymbolicName());
    }
    ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(LogService.class.getName());
    if (ref == null) {
        System.out.println("service ref. is null");
    } else {
        LogService ls  = (LogService) context.getService(ref);
             if (ls == null) {
               System.out.println(" Log is Null");
            } else {
               ls.log(LogService.LOG_DEBUG, "aaaaHahahahahaha");
             }
    }
}
```

Here is some part of MANIFEST.MF of that bundle

```
   Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.5.0",
                   org.osgi.service.log;version="1.3.0",
                   org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.0"
   Bundle-Activator: com.ktbcs.cjmf.log.factory.activator.LogServiceFactoryActivator
```

I sure that osgi-over-slf4j already ACTIVE.
My environment is Websphere 8.5 on windows 8.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

anurak

Comment: Could you please tell which bundles you use exactly? Which implementation of slf4j and which version? Is it possible that osgi-over-slf4j starts later than your bundle? In that case there is no LogService when your Activator is called yet.

Comment: hi @Balazs, thanks for you response. i used osgi-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar bundle. I have two client bundles, when install the first one it can not find a log service but i saw in the osgi console that log service already registered. So i install the second client bundle it still can not find a log service. What do u think?

Comment: Osgi-over-slf4j is only a wrapper. You need to have the api and an implementation, too (like slf4j-simple). Do you have an implementation? If you use equinox, that it had an own Logservice by default and the bundle contains the Logservice API. Your bundle might be wired to another API than slf4j so the service reference cannot be found by your bundle.

Comment: I found the root cause, because i tried to get the service from Activator class. Like you said may be osgi-over-slf4j start later than my bundle. Thanks again.

Comment: I made an answer from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle starts earlier then osgi-over-slf4j. In that case, the service cannot be found in the start function of the Activator.

To avoid this issue, you can use Declarative Services or one of its alternative instead of an Activator.